# Unable to download laser.bag

Tags: laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear folks,

I am following this tutorial to use laser scanner. "[Introduction to Working With Laser Scanner Data](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_pipeline/Tutorials/IntroductionToWorkingWithLaserScannerData)"

I will receive my Laser scanner in a few months so I need some raw data to test and develop my program beforehand. When I attempt to download the raw data from the tutorial by this [link](http://vault.willowgarage.com/wgdata1/vol1/wiki_docs/laser_pipeline/laser.bag), I receive a message that I don't have permission to access the data. Anyone has the same problem? or do you know where else I can find raw laser scanner data to test?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211361/unable-to-download-laser.bag/) by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 397 on 2015-06-15

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [timster](https://answers.ros.org/users/3358/timster/) on 2015-06-15**:
right click, save as

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also get

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access
> /wgdata1/vol1/wiki_docs/laser_pipeline/laser.bag
> on this server.

http://vault.willowgarage.com/wgdata1/vol1/wiki_docs/laser_pipeline/laser.bag is an old willowgarage.com link, the website still exists but they cleaned out the wiki in the move to ros.org, but that file slipped through the cracks?

I made a note on the wiki page about it.  It looks like no one else had edited the page in five years.  If no one else responds to this message with one you could make a new post asking for an example LaserScan bag file.  I think I have a hokuyo somewhere, if I can find it I could generate a bag and upload it.

---

Update

http://classes.engineering.wustl.edu/cse550/a02.php has a couple of bags with LaserScans in them:  http://classes.engineering.wustl.edu/cse550/data/Mapping1.bag

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2015-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1